# Android C2DM Registration, BroadCastReceiver never called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm

I'm having some trouble implementing C2DM registration. My BroadcastReceiver is never called.

I'm working with the emulator (Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 8) with my gmail account set up. It seems to work because the BroadcastReceiver of the Thomas Malmsten exemple is working fine on my emulator ([link](https://github.com/tomasmalmsten/c2dm-android-pilot)).

```
Here is my manifest :

<permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:name=".utils.MyApp" ...>

   <receiver android:name=".C2DMBroadCastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <!-- Receive the actual message -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="my.package" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Receive the registration id -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <catemgory android:name="my.package" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".views.LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- lots of activities -->
    <!-- lots of services -->

</application>
```

For now, I just want to write something in the logcat.

```
My Broadcast Receiver
package my.package;

import ...;

public class C2DMBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("C2DMBroadCastReceiver ", "Received something from Google.");
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            Log.d("C2DMBroadCastReceiver ", "Received a registration ID from Google.");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            Log.d("C2DMBroadCastReceiver ", "Received a C2DM message from Google.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my registration fonction :

```
Context context = MyApp.getAppContext();
            Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
            registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0)); 
            registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "myC2DMaddress@gmail.com");
            Log.w("Register", "Intent to register");
            context.startService(registrationIntent);
```

Finaly, the logcat :

```
W/Register(  344): Intent to register
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=my.package/.views.Conver
sationList }
D/GoogleLoginService(  173): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthen
ticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
D/dalvikvm(  173): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4630 objects / 378200 bytes in 133ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1799 objects / 279192 bytes in 95ms
D/NativeCrypto(  344): Freeing OpenSSL session
I/ActivityManager(   58): Displayed activity my.package/.views.ConversationList: 1
352 ms (total 1352 ms)
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2170 objects / 476328 bytes in 90ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6985 objects / 461360 bytes in 151ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 612 objects / 32376 bytes in 153ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  344): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.239MB for 87396-byte allocati
on
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24 objects / 1736 bytes in 51ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 146ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  344): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.321MB for 87396-byte allocati
on
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 53ms
D/NativeCrypto(  344): Freeing OpenSSL session
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1080 objects / 244032 bytes in 122ms
I/global  (  344): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It wo
uld be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1077 objects / 120272 bytes in 53ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  344): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.506MB for 87396-byte allocati
on
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 375 objects / 24096 bytes in 52ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3 objects / 104 bytes in 49ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  344): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.567MB for 87396-byte allocati
on
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 146ms
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 16 bytes in 49ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  344): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.733MB for 87396-byte allocati
on
D/dalvikvm(  344): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 146ms
I/global  (  344): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It wo
uld be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
```

Sorry about all the code, but i really don't know what's going on!

Thank you,
    Matthieu

ps : It's not working either with a Nexus One.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really stupid mistake : catemgory instead of category in the manifest.